# Are there any good utilities out there to create datastore / LUN diagrams for VMware ESX 3.5?

Tags: vmware-esx, lun

We are working to get a large (inherited) VMware ESX 3.5 environment with multiple SANs under control.  We first need to create a diagram / Excel spreadsheet / whatever that explains what VM is stored where.  This is a rather time-consuming task to complete by just using the VI client to copy down everything.  Is there a good script or tool out there that can do this for us?

I would like to see: 
VM Name, LUN, Actual file-name/location of VMDK/VMX, Power State, Host

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a simple utility **rvtools** for this

Comment: Fantastic!  This gave me what I needed in just a few seconds.  What a relief!